# Xpath query to grab text between different html tags

Tags: html, r, xpath

I am using R to screen scrape. I've grabbed a page and I've managed to find all the links on the page that found in a certain place on the page (anchor tags within anchor tags with a name attribute) using:

```
links <- xpathSApply(doc, "//a[@name]//a/@href")
```

Now I have grabbed got the documents from the links with Curl and I want to scrape a certain amount of text. The text seems to always be between an `<p>` tag (although there are other `<p>` tags in the text and end before the following text

```
</pre><hr>Back to: <a href="#TOP">
```

I decided to grab all the text between `<p>` and `<a href="#TOP">` and I cant seem to nail the xpath query. So far I have got:

```
text <- xpathSApply(doc, '"/ //text()[preceding:://a/@href="#TOP"] and following::*//p')
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? There are quite a few xpath answers on stackoverflow but they don't always explain the answer which makes it hard to edit them for my  own use.

Sample HTML:

```
<span ID="MSGHDR-CONTENT-TYPE-H-PRE">Content-type:</b></span> <span ID="MSGHDR-CONTENT-        TYPE-PRE">text/plain; charset=us-ascii</span>
</span><p> 

lots and lots of text here that I want


</pre><hr>Back to: <a href="#TOP">Top of message</a> &#124; <a href="/cgi-bin/wa?A1=ind9709&L=cybcom&D=0">Previous page</a> &#124; <a href="/cgi-bin/wa?A0=cybcom&D=0">Main CYBCOM page</a><p>
```

Comment: Give also the sample HTML please

Comment: which texts you want to grab.?

Comment: everything between <p> and </pre>. There are more <p> tags in the text and the opening <pre tag is above the inital <p> if that makes sense.

Comment: I need the full block of content.. this is not telling under which `<p>` and `<pre>` are sitting..

Comment: [Does a link to an example page help?](https://hermes.gwu.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind9709&L=cybcom&D=0&P=1120)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is badly formed, so it was difficult for me to figure out what a well-formed instance would look like when parsed into a tree of nodes.

Something like the following might work. It assumes that all of the `<p>` elements declared inside of the `<pre>` are children of it (even though not closed in the HTML).

It looks for the `text()` that is a child of the `<p>` that does not have a child `<p>` and is a descendant of the `<pre>` that has a following-sibling who's first `<a>` has an href with the value "#TOP".

```
//body/pre[following-sibling::a[position()=1 and @href='#TOP']]//p[not(p)]/text()
```